# For Dynamodb DAX are the requests charged even when there is a cache hit i.e item is fetched from dax cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Lets suppose I have a dynamodb table with 10 frequently accessed items of around 8KB each.
I decided to use dax infront of the table.
I got total 1 million read requests for the items.

a. Will I be charged for 10 dynamodb requests, since only 10 requests made it to dynamodb and rest were fetched from dax cache itself, 
or
b.  will I be charged for all 1 million dynamodb requests.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question, and asked AWS. The answer I received was:

> Whenever DAX has the item available (a cache hit), DAX returns the
> item to the application without accessing DynamoDB. In that case, the
> request will not consume read capacity units (RCUs) from DynamoDB
> table and hence there will not be any DynamoDB cost for that
> [request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.html#DAX.use-cases). Therefore, if you have 10k requests and out of that if
> only 2k requests goes to DynamoDB, the total charge which gets charged
> will be for the 2k read request charge for DynamoDB, running cost for
> DAX cluster and data transfer charges (if applicable).

Answer (score -2):

> DynamoDB charges for DAX capacity by the hour and your DAX instances
>   run with no long-term commitments. Pricing is per node-hour consumed
>   and is dependent on the instance type you select. Each partial
>   node-hour consumed is billed as a full hour. Pricing applies to all
>   individual nodes in the DAX cluster. For example, if you have a
>   three-node DAX cluster, you are billed for each of the separate nodes
>   (three nodes in total) on an hourly basis.

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: Yes but nothing is said as to how the requests are charged.
DAX cluster charges are clear but will a cache hit also be counted as valid dynamodb request

Comment: @PrashantPriyadarshi DAX page says `you only pay for the capacity you provision`. If you have doubts, then better source would be AWS support or forums.